# Golang s3 getting no file found and server panic on uploading image

Tags: go, amazon-s3

Hello first of i am new to Golang and am trying to upload a photo to my s3 Bucket however I am getting an error every time I try, the error I get is this

**err opening file: open 55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg: no such file or directory2016/11/30 19:28:10 http: panic serving [::1]:58502: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 5 [running]**

My buckets permission are set to read and write for everyone so it must be something in this code is that wrong

and I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@questhenkart/s3-image-uploads-via-aws-sdk-with-golang-63422857c548#.ahda1pgly and I am trying to upload a public image found here http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/,scalefit_950_800_noupscale/55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg

my current code is this below

```
func UploadProfile(w http.ResponseWriter) {

    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key,token)
    _, err := creds.Get()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("bad credentials: %s", err)
    }

    config := &aws.Config{
        Region          :aws.String("us-west-1"),
        Endpoint        :aws.String("s3.amazonaws.com"),
        S3ForcePathStyle:aws.Bool(true),
        Credentials     :creds,
    }

    svc := s3.New(session.New(), config)
    file, err := os.Open("55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err opening file: %s", err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    var size int64 = fileInfo.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size)

    file.Read(buffer)
    fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(buffer)
    fileType := http.DetectContentType(buffer)

    path := "http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/,scalefit_950_800_noupscale/" + file.Name()
    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("MyBucket"),
        Key: aws.String(path),
        Body: fileBytes,
        ContentLength: aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType: aws.String(fileType),
    }
    resp, err := svc.PutObject(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("bad response: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("response %s", awsutil.StringValue(resp))

    fmt.Fprintf(w,"done")

}
```

I do not know why this is not working as my Credentials and buckets are correct . In addition the IMG address works for the image above so do not know why the file is nil

```
<img height="200" width="200" src="http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/,scalefit_950_800_noupscale/55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg"/>
```

Comment: You can't use the file if there was an error opening it. You're essentially ignoring the error you're printing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1591668,

Your error is "err opening file: open 55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg: no such file or directory". Sounds like not related to AWS's SDK.

Check that your binary actually starts in the *same* directory where your image file is ("working directory") or, to test this assumption, you can try with an absolute path to the image.

Cheers,
Dennis